# Consuming API from website

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm developing a website and REST API which are a part of the same project folder.

I've developed a REST api as below

```
URL: example.com/login
Type: POST
Request Body:
{
    "credentials": {
        "username":"dd",
        "password":"dd"
    },
    "appInfo": {
        "version": "1.0"
    }
}
```

In the login method (UserController) I'm fetching the request body as below

```
json_decode(Request::instance()->getContent());
```

Now I'm developing a webpage and want to invoke this API from there. I'm using the below code (HomeController)

```
public function acceptlogin(Request $request) {
    $data = array(
        'credentials'=> array(
            'username'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>$request->password
        ),
        'appInfo'=> array(
            'version'=> "1.0"
        )
    );
    $request1 = Request::create('example.com/login', 'POST', $data);
    $response = Route::dispatch($request1);
}
```

I'm able to invoke the login api from the above code but the below code in the login method returns empty.

```
json_decode(Request::instance()->getContent());
```

Can you please suggest on how to invoke a local API (within the same project) in Laravel

Comment: What does `Request::instance()->getContent()` return exactly? Have you `var_dump`ed it?

Comment: `$request->pasword`. Maybe it is just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed with a workaround. I'm using the below code to invoke LoginController

```
(new UserController)->loginNew($data)
```